# Testing coroutines in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, junit, kotlin-coroutines

I have this simple test about a crawler that is supposed to call the repo 40 times:

```
@Test
fun testX() {
   // ... 
   runBlocking {
        crawlYelp.concurrentCrawl()
        // Thread.sleep(5000) // works if I un-comment
   }
   verify(restaurantsRepository, times(40)).saveAll(restaurants)
   // ...
}
```

and this implementation:

```
suspend fun concurrentCrawl() {
    cities.map { loc ->
        1.rangeTo(10).map { start ->
            GlobalScope.async {
                val rests = scrapYelp.scrap(loc, start * 10)
                restaurantsRepository.saveAll(rests)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But... I get this:

```
Wanted 40 times:
-> at ....testConcurrentCrawl(CrawlYelpTest.kt:46)
But was 30 times:
```

(the 30 is changing all the time; so it seems the test is not waiting...)

Why does it pass when I do the sleep? It should not be needed given I run blocking..

BTW, I have a controller that is supposed to be kept asynchronous:

```
@PostMapping("crawl")
suspend fun crawl(): String {
    crawlYelp.concurrentCrawl()
    return "crawling" // this is supposed to be returned right away
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`runBlocking` waits for all suspend functions to finish, but as `concurrentCrawl` basically just starts new jobs in new threads with `GlobalScope.async` `currentCrawl`, and therefore `runBlocking`, is done after all jobs were started and not after all of this jobs have finished.

You have to wait for all jobs started with `GlobalScope.async` to finish like this:

```
suspend fun concurrentCrawl() {
    cities.map { loc ->
        1.rangeTo(10).map { start ->
            GlobalScope.async {
                val rests = scrapYelp.scrap(loc, start * 10)
                restaurantsRepository.saveAll(rests)
            }
        }.awaitAll()
    }
}
```

If you want to wait for `concurrentCrawl()` to finish outside of `concurrentCrawl()` then you have to pass the `Deferred` results to the calling function like in the following example. In that case the `suspend` keyword can be removed from `concurrentCrawl()`.

```
fun concurrentCrawl(): List<Deferred<Unit>> {
    return cities.map { loc ->
        1.rangeTo(10).map { start ->
            GlobalScope.async {
                println("hallo world $start")
            }
        }
    }.flatten()
}


runBlocking {
    concurrentCrawl().awaitAll()
}
```

As mentioned in the comments: In this case the `async` method does not return any value so it is better to use launch instead:

```
fun concurrentCrawl(): List<Job> {
    return cities.map { loc ->
        1.rangeTo(10).map { start ->
            GlobalScope.launch {
                println("hallo world $start")
            }
        }
    }.flatten()
}

runBlocking {
    concurrentCrawl().joinAll()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But won't that make `concurrentCall` be blocking? Or is that `awaitAll` in the context of the threads?

Comment: Yes this makes `concurrentCrawl` blocking but the individual crawls will be carried out in parallel. If you want to wait for the jobs to continue outside of `concurrentCrawl` you have to pass the job to the calling function. I included an example for that in my answer

Comment: was the `suspend` needed? I'm not sure from the docs when it should be used. thanks!

Comment: In the first case, `awaitAll` suspends so `concurrentCrawl` must be a `suspend fun`. In the second case it never suspends, therefore it shouldn't be a `suspend fun`. Also, don't use `async` when you aren't getting a result value from the coroutine. Basically, `Deferred<Unit>` is a code smell all of its own.

Comment: So.. suspending means it can run in parallel or suspended without blocking the main flow right?
Regarding `Deferred<Unit>`, I suppose you mean I should use `launch` instead.

Comment: Yes, use `launch` and `Job.join()` instead of `Deferred.await()`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `Deferred<Unit>` code smell. Added the `launch` version to the answer

Answer (score 3):

You could also just use [MockK](https://mockk.io) for this (and so much more).

MockK's `verify` has a `timeout : Long` parameter specifically for handling these races in tests.

You could leave your production code as it is, and change your test to this:

```
import io.mockk.verify

@Test
fun `test X`() = runBlocking {
   // ... 

   crawlYelp.concurrentCrawl()

   verify(exactly = 40, timeout = 5000L) {
      restaurantsRepository.saveAll(restaurants)
   }
   // ...
}
```

If the verify is successful at any point before 5 seconds, it'll pass and move on.  Else, the verify (and test) will fail.